# access form data in view

Tags: django, python-3.x

I hava a form in my template which is for search.I did not made any form class to it. Is it possible to have access form data in view or should I make a form class to it.

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" action="{% url 'my_url_name' %}" method="get">
 <div class="input-group add-on">
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" type="text">
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
  </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I use this form for its style and I can not make this style with Form class

Comment: The *only* things that you have customised in that form field is the placeholder and the form-control class, both of which are trivial to do in a the Form class.

Comment: I did not know that. I will try to learn Forms deeper. but what about the answer

Comment: You can find form data in request.GET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access form data in the `request.GET` (or `request.POST` if it is a post request) dictionary in your view. For example:

```
srch_term = request.GET.get('srch-term')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can by using the [*QueryDict*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) object you get with the request :

```
def myview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST
        print(data['foo'])  # <--Will print the value I entered into my form.
    [...]
```

But be careful with this : There is no validation tool to ensure the data you receive is correctly formated.